# Why fastbook (fast.ai) is using a star import?

Tags: python, import, fast-ai

Usually in Python, it is recommended to never do a "star import" (e.g. `from my_module import *`).

The rationale is that it makes it hard to read, perform linting, and even worse could lead to clash of name (More on this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/)).

However, all the documentation and training of fast.ai through the usage of `fastbook` use the following lines:

```py
import fastbook
fastbook.setup_book()

from fastbook import *
```

Why shall we use `import *` for `fastbook`?

How feasible would it be to do `import fastbook as fb` instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the founder of fast.ai - Jeremy Howard, It is OK to use star import if you are using an interactive work environment like jupyter notebook. Below is what Jeremy says in his book "Deep Learning for Coders With Fastai and Pytorch AI Applications without a PhD":

*"A lot of Python coders recommend avoiding importing a whole library like this (using the import * syntax) because in large software projects it can cause problems. However, for interactive work such as in a Jupyter notebook, it works great. The fastai library is specially designed to support this kind of interactive use, and it will import only the necessary pieces into your environment."*

Comment: I have a ton of respect for these authors but I think this is a bad way to steer people. I have replaced all the start imports with stuff like "import fasai.vision.all as fv" and figured out in the code where I have to replace things. I find it really helps me learn what pieces are part of the modules. I just spent about 40 minutes finally figuring out that plot_function is a fastbook function and that I needed to install that seperately. Actually using hints as to what modules you are learning helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

They probably just do it in whatever example you're following because it's easy to get everything into the namespace in examples to make them more compact

The unrelated [Sympy docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) also show a wildcard import for this reason

There's no problem having the import directly or naming it, and you should likely do this for any shared code.

One of their [example notebooks](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/06_multicat.ipynb) does the import as you might expect

```py
import fastbook
```

Comment: I had the same feeling as you. I should try to run the examples with a proper import. Note that in the example you provide you have `import fastbook` but it's because you just do a `fastbook.setup_book()`, which is then followed by `from fastbook import *`. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

While the author stated that

> "A lot of Python coders recommend avoiding importing a whole library
> like this (using the import * syntax) because in large software
> projects it can cause problems. However, for interactive work such as
> in a Jupyter notebook, it works great. The fastai library is specially
> designed to support this kind of interactive use, and it will import
> only the necessary pieces into your environment."

, it seems like such practice is all over the entire fastai library itself rather than just the demos in interactive works:

In fastai.layers:

```
from .imports import *
from .torch_imports import *
from .torch_core import *
from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm, spectral_norm
```

Now combine such practice with their notation convention and suboptimal documentation, you can understand the torment of both beginner users and developers.

Comment: `the torment of both beginner users and developers`: Well put :)